# Unable to create new gnupg object in Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony, gnupg, pgp, gpg-signature

I am converting a project from pure PHP to Symfony and I am having problems working with gnupg in Symfony.

My problem is the following: I configured gnupg following PHP's docs without any problem, I restarted my webserver and I also restarted the php-fpm. I just created a single php file to check if all was correctly configured and all works fine with pure php. The problem comes when I try to add the code into my Symfony's controller. When I do the following:

```
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/home/kevingrab/.gnupg');
$gpg = '/usr/bin/gpg';
$gpg = new gnupg();
```

I obtain the following error in the logs:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "gnupg" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 147 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ClassNotFoundException(code: 0): Attempted to load class \"gnupg\" from namespace \"AppBundle\\Controller\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace? at /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php:147)"} []
```

And well I don't know what can I do to fix it, I tried to find an answer in internet but I didn't see any post about this issue with Symfony. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fix your issue by prepending  `\` to the code which is instantiating the gnupg object.

So

```
$gpg = new \gnupg();
```

To know why this is the case, refer to [Global space.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the "\" as you told me but I am getting the same error yet... Your reply has sense but I am getting the same error

Comment: may be its not installed ? sudo pecl gnupg

Comment: Yeah, it is installed and it is working with a simple php script but not inside the Symfony's controller

Comment: On CentOS 7 before I could install with pecl, I did: `sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php72 install php-pear php-devel` and then `sudo pecl install gnupg` and then edited my php.ini to contain `extension=gnupg.so` and restarted apache2 with `sudo systemctl restart httpd`